# Why is there no locking issues when doing context.write in hadoop reducer

Tags: hadoop, file-io

I'm confused as to how conext.write works in hadoop reducer.
Why is there no locking issues in hadoop reducers(if there is more than 1 reducer) if all are writing to the same file in HDFS?

Normally, if we would write to the same file ourselves in a hadoop mapper/reducer, we would get locking errors that we can't write to the same file concurrently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your map reduce program runs on a Multi node cluster then there will be unique Map and Reduce programs running on each node.

Reduce in Map Reduce doesn't directly write to the file itself. It delegates this task to OutputFormat which is responsible for sinking of Data. It could be to a File, Database Table or any other location. FileOutputFormat will sink to a location in Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS). DBOutputFormat will sink to a Database table (read this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/storing-hadoop-wordcount-example-with.html)).

For your question of file locks please have a look at this [post](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#dataflow) at Yahoo Developer Network.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I guess I missed the point that each reducer writes to a separate file called part-nnnnn